# When adding "--" to animate a slide in RMarkdown, bullet point shifts

Tags: css, r, markdown

I'm writing up a presentation in RMarkdown. When using the `--` between 2 lines (to animate the slide), I sometimes have an extra indentations *between the bullet and the text*.

See the source [code here](https://github.com/beausoleilmo/Rsimulation).

```
---
## Find patterns in random processes

- Simulations are useful to test the properties of randomly generated data 
- Since we designed the simulation, we know parameters of the processes that underlie it.

--

- It is then possible to test various methods to 
    1. see if they work and verify their assumptions, 
    2. do power analysis, 
    3. learn how data is generated
    4. etc.
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug in the library you're using. But when you roll the mouse a new class is applied to the html element, funny is that in some slides the first element is not being added to this class. What makes this weird effect. Probably there is a bug in the "qcbsR.css" file

Answer (score 0):

Just found this answer here:
https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Markdown#incremental-slides

Basically, you shall NOT add a space before the to dashes `--`

So the code should be:

```
---
## Find patterns in random processes

- Simulations are useful to test the properties of randomly generated data 
- Since we designed the simulation, we know parameters of the processes that underlie it.
--

- It is then possible to test various methods to 
    1. see if they work and verify their assumptions, 
    2. do power analysis, 
    3. learn how data is generated
    4. etc.
```

I tested it and it now works.